# Ошибка при статической компиляции CURL?

Tags: c++, curl

Ошибка при сборке статического бинарника с CURL, если собирать не статический то все собирается нормально, что не так?(CURL устанавливал из MSYS2)
Команда которой собирал:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -w *.cpp -lcurl -o test.exe -static
```

Версия Компилятора:

```
gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Ошибка:

```
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: А статическая библиотека curl имеется?

Comment: в папке lib, есть две libcurl:
1. libcurl.a
2. libcurl.dll.a

Comment: Все тоже самое.